# Modify tab indicator dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

My application needs to update tab indicator dynamically, I'm trying to do this by invoke TabSpec.setIndicator(), but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

In onCreate method of TabActivity:

```
tabHost = getTabHost(); 
TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("abc");
tabSpec.setIndicator("helloabc");
tabSpec.setContent(new MyViewFactory());
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Now I need to change tab indicator to another string, for example, "xyz"

```
TabSpec tabSpec = MyTabActivity.getTabSpec();
tabSpec.setIndicator("xyz");
```

But it doesn't work. So I'd like to know how to change tab indicator after it is added to the tabhost? Many thanks.

**Solution**

Thanks to @CommonsWare, I make it by using TabWidget.getChildAt, here is my code for your convenience:

```
TextView title = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabId).findViewById(android.R.id.title)
title.setText("xyz");
```

Comment: can i change the image indicator this way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I apologize for my earlier incorrect answer, now deleted.

Try using [`getChildViewAt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html#getChildTabViewAt(int)) on `TabWidget`.

Comment: How can i change the image indicator of tab bar?

Answer (score 7):

i managaed with `getChildTabViewAt(tabId)` instead of `childviewAt(id)` for multiple tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 TextView title = (TextView) TabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tabId).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
```